# Why does an iOS 15 Capability not work if built with XCode 12.5?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, entitlements, ios15

In my app, I enabled some of the Capabilities which were added for iOS 15.
I've re-generated the provisioning profile and updated the Entitlements file.

The app compiles successfully with both Xcode13 beta and Xcode 12.5.
However, when installed to iOS 15 device, the capability doesn't work for the binary built with Xcode 12.5.

I've checked if the capability is incorporated into the binary, it's OK:

```
codesign --display --entitlements :- MyIosApp.app
```

Do you know or assume the logic of handling the Capabilites on iOS side?

If an iOS app is valid, well signed, provisioning profile is OK, then can the system have the logic like "*Oh, this Capability should work for iOS 15, and this is iOS 15 device. And the app contains a proper entitlement. But the app was built with Xcode12, which doesn't have iOS 15 SDK, so let's ignore this Capability*" ?

And can I somehow force the system to handle this particular Capability, even if the app was built with the lower SDK?